# how can i extract the questions as well as answers in PHP using preg_match or any other technique

Tags: php, mysql

below is the word file i am uploading and i have so far managed to read all the contents from the word file.

now i want to insert it in mysql table :

below is what i have extracted from word file :

(Q.1#   **Study the following information carefully answers the given questions.** 
    Eight people- M, N, O, P, R, S, T and U representing four countries, India, China, Spain and Russia are sitting around a circular table facing the centre of the table, in an international event. Two people are representing each countries, but not necessarily in the same order. People are from different professions i.e. -Doctor, Author, Banker, Engineer, Politician, Scientist, Economist and Entrepreneur. No two representatives of the same countries are sitting adjacent to each other except those of China. Engineer is sitting on the immediate left of the entrepreneur. R is neither the Entrepreneur nor the Banker. U, the Scientist, represents Spain and is sitting immediate left of N, who represents China. N is not the Banker. S is Politician and is from China, who is sitting opposite to T. Only Author M is sitting between Engineer T and the Economist. Representatives of India are sitting opposite to each other. Both the representative of Russia is sitting adjacent to representative of India. P is not the entrepreneur. 
    Which of the following pair sitting adjacent to Politician?
    1). N and U 2). R and P 3). P and U 4). U and O 5). None of these
Ans- Option5

(Q.2#   **Study the following information carefully answers the given questions.** 
    Eight people- M, N, O, P, R, S, T and U representing four countries, India, China, Spain and Russia are sitting around a circular table facing the centre of the table, in an international event. Two people are representing each countries, but not necessarily in the same order. People are from different professions i.e. -Doctor, Author, Banker, Engineer, Politician, Scientist, Economist and Entrepreneur. No two representatives of the same countries are sitting adjacent to each other except those of China. Engineer is sitting on the immediate left of the entrepreneur. R is neither the Entrepreneur nor the Banker. U, the Scientist, represents Spain and is sitting immediate left of N, who represents China. N is not the Banker. S is Politician and is from China, who is sitting opposite to T. Only Author M is sitting between Engineer T and the Economist. Representatives of India are sitting opposite to each other. Both the representative of Russia is sitting adjacent to representative of India. P is not the entrepreneur. 
    Who is the Doctor ?
    1). N 2). P 3). O 4). R 5). None of these
Ans- Option1

Anyone please help me out.

Comment: a quick search should provide many, many articles about inserting data into a database

Comment: i know about inserting.. i asked about how can i extract the question and answer part from the following output that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern;

```
preg_match_all("/(\(Q.*)/s", $string , $matches);
```

It will look for `(Q` as each question starts like that and capture everything til next question starts.

The option `/s` means it will accept dot as new line.

You can see it here: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/n4T
Just be sure to click on preg_match_all

Comment: thanks. I want to bifurcate question and answers and correct answer separately in the array ?

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question.